# How to solve Win 10 "unable to establish networks connections"?

Tags: networking, windows-10, voip, dell-latitude

This has been happening since upgrade from Win 7 to Win 10. Service packs are up to date.

I use vBuzzer voip application as my phone.

Since the upgrade to Win 10, the phone does not work properly, in or out. An error message appears when I dial out "unable to establish networks connections". Incoming calls go straight to voicemail.

vBuzzer help is very sparse, but I was able to get in touch enough to understand that from their side, everything is working properly. That leaves the upgrade.

My computer is a Dell E6420. When I go to their site to update driver(s), I receive the message that they do not support this model for Windows 10.

I have no proxy enabled.

I checked this question: [How to solve: Intel Network driver won't install? "no supported network connection exists", Windows 10, Dell Latitude E6420](https://superuser.com/questions/1114898/how-to-solve-intel-network-driver-wont-install-no-supported-network-connecti), looked at "device manager" and there are no signs of a problem.

Is there some switch I can throw to connect this application?

Comment: Have you enabled the correct ports in your firewall?

Comment: This is way beyond me. I have no idea how to deal with this. My windows firewall is off. I have Comodo installed. I can probably find the firewall in Comodo but at that point I have no idea what to do.